# Queries on "Get Regex matches" in Robocorp

Tags: regex, robotframework

I have a form in MS Word which the user fills and emails me. I have to open the form and capture all the details entered by the user and use the same to submit a form in my portal.

I am trying to create a robot using Robocorp to automate this process. Using "Get All texts" - RPA Word library, I am logging the contents from the Word document in Robocorp and then trying to get the required data using Regex but need some help on extracting the data using Regex.

Please find the raw text logged in Robocorp below,
[Source Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqTTR.png)

Query 1:

Need to extract Manager name:

- In Regex101, I am getting the name returned as expected upon using, [^Manager\n].*
- In Robocorp, when I use 'Get regex matches' with [^Manager\n].*, I am getting all the content of the text file.
  Please help me with the regex to use in Robocorp to extract the Manager name.

Query 2:

I need to extract the answers provided by the user for the questions in the above form. (Note: The answers change with every form submitted)
I tried the below,

For eg:  I pulled one question first from the above form using - Get Regex matches (?s)(Lunch).*?(No).
I got the below value returned in robocorp,
['Lunch account required? \x07☒ Yes\r☐ No']

Now again from this value returned (using this as string), I tried to get the answer selected by the user using,
Get Regex matches (?<=☒)\s\w+

But I am getting the error "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object".

Not sure, If the above flow is right or can I get the answers selected by the user for all questions in a different way?

Sorry if my questions are simple. I am totally new to using Regex and in my learning phase.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Take a look at the part about escaping backslashes [here](https://robocorp.com/docs/libraries/built-in/builtin#Regular%20expressions) and the examples about group matching [here](https://robocorp.com/docs/libraries/built-in/builtin/keywords#should-match-regexp) on the Robocorp docs, the latter may work in avoiding lookarounds. Aside from that, for your first query you could take the new line outside of the capturing group and for your second query (if I understand it right) you could use a structure like this, with a negative character class: `question[^☒]*☒ (\\w+)`.

Comment: It is really difficult to say anything about errors, because the source text and queries you show in your question seem not to correspond. Please format your question to make it more readable. For example, you expect a new line after the manager as per your expression, but the source text has no new line there, and so on.

Comment: Finally, here is an example for [Get Regexp Matches](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Get%20Regexp%20Matches) which also shows how to access `(grouped)` data.

Comment: @oriberu - Sorry for that, This is my first post and saw that the text I copied had spacing issues on pasting it here. I have edited the post completely. Please read and kindly help on it.